# Creating an object with new vs $this

Tags: php

I have recently been working on a project that was thrown upon me at work after another developer left (he was the only one working on it prior to leaving). The project was written in CodeIgniter and uses the MVC framework. While working on the project I noticed something funny or at least something I have not seen before.
After the model is loaded into the controller the object is passed into the view using...

```
$data['outcomes']                 = $this->id_conversion;
```

With id_conversion being the model that was loaded in at the top of the controller. My question is is this any different then using

```
new Id_conversion();
```

in place of the above.

Thanks for any help or anyone able to point me in the correct direction.

Edit. Sorry after reading the comments I see that I need more of my code for this to make sense.

```
public function person($id)
{
    $this->authenticate->check_access(array('admin', 'rps'), 'home');
    $this->load->library('page_uri');
    $this->load->model('term');
    $this->load->model('user');
            $this->load->model('id_conversion');

    $selected_term = $this->page_uri->get_term();

    $current_term = $this->term->current_term_id();
    if (!isset($selected_term)) {
        $selected_term = $current_term;
    }

    $term = new Term();
    if (!empty($selected_term) && $selected_term !== '0') {
        $term = new Term($selected_term);
    }

    $user = new User($id);
    $plans = $user->plans_by_term($term);

    $data = array();
    $data['user']                 = $user;
    $data['site_url']             = site_url("reports/person");
    $data['current_term']                     = $this->term->current_term_id();
    $data['selected_term']                    = $selected_term;
    $data['terms']                = $this->term->sorted_term_list();
    $data['term']                 = $selected_term;
    $data['plans']                = $plans;
            $data['outcomes']                         = $this->id_conversion;

    $this->load->view('template/foundation', $data);
}
```

the model id_conversion loads in

```
class Id_conversion extends MY_Model{

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

/*
 * Input a primary or secondary outcome as defined
 * in the plan class and 
 */
public function id_outcomes($id)
{
    $sql = 'SELECT name
            FROM outcomes
            WHERE id ='. $id;

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    return $query->row_array();
}
```

}

Comment: It's different if `$this->id_conversion` was initialized differently...  and yes it's different in other subtle ways.

Comment: And it creates another instance of the class, which may not be desirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `new` will create a new object.

Using `$this->id_conversion` will use the existing object that was already created at some point previously and which was stored in that variable.

Without seeing more of your code, it's utterly impossible to know what state the existing object is in, so I can't tell you what difference it will make to create a new one compared with using the existing one. I would imagine there's a good reason for the program to have already created the object and stored it for you, so I guess it's been set up ready for use, but I can't tell for sure from what you've given us.

But even in the case that the existing object is in an entirely pristine condition and creating a new one would give identical functionality, you'd be wasting system resources in creating an extra object when one already exists. Only a small amount of wastage, to be sure, but it all adds up.

Answer (score 1):

It's *probably* going to give the same results but not certainly.

If `$this->id_conversion` is a reference to a model class, that class may have been initialized in a different way. In Codeigniter, you can initialize an instance of a model like this:

```
$this->load->model('model_name', 'alias_name', $db_params);
```

If the class `Id_conversion` doesn't exist and `id_conversion` is actually an alias, then of course that wouldn't work.

If `$db_params` are different, then this is much different than just saying `new Id_conversion();`. Note also that the `()` are not needed if you aren't passing anything to the constructor. And as mentioned, it creates another unnecessary instance of the class.

And of course, if the state of `$this->id_conversion` has changed at all, for example:

```
$this->id_conversion->property = 'value';
```

...then it will not be the same at all.

Note that `$this->id_conversion` will be available in the view as well, so while it's probably good practice to explicitly pass it to the view, it isn't strictly necessary. The view runs in the same scope from the controller method that it was called in.

Better to stick to the Codeigniter way unless you are sure you know what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks a ton! that really cleared it up for me. Just to check my understanding $this->id_conversion is creating a reference to the class?